# Unescaping characters in a string with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, escaping, httparty, posterous

Given a string in the following format (the Posterous API returns posts in this format):

```
s="\\u003Cp\\u003E"
```

How can I convert it to the actual ascii characters such that `s="<p>"`?

On OSX, I successfully used `Iconv.iconv('ascii', 'java', s)` but once deployed to Heroku, I receive an `Iconv::IllegalSequence` exception. I'm guessing that the system Heroku deploys to does't support the `java` encoder.

---

I am using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to make a request to the Posterous API. If I use curl to make the same request then I do *not* get the double slashes.

From HTTParty github page:

> Automatic parsing of JSON and XML into
>   ruby hashes based on response
>   content-type

The Posterous API returns JSON (no double slashes) and HTTParty's JSON parsing is inserting the double slash.

---

Here is a simple example of the way I am using HTTParty to make the request.

```
class Posterous
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://www.posterous.com/api/2"
  basic_auth "username", "password"
  format :json
  def get_posts
    response = Posterous.get("/users/me/sites/9876/posts&api_token=1234")
    # snip, see below...
  end
end
```

With the obvious information (username, password, site_id, api_token) replaced with valid values.

At the point of snip, `response.body` contains a Ruby string that is in JSON format and `response.parsed_response` contains a Ruby hash object which HTTParty created by parsing the JSON response from the Posterous API.

In both cases the unicode sequences such as `\u003C` have been changed to `\\u003C`.

Comment: do you use the same version of ruby on you system as it is used on heroku ?

Comment: It looks like they are both running 1.8.7.

Comment: HTTParty has a [`format`](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/master/HTTParty/ClassMethods#format-instance_method) command that lets you specify the format being returned and to be parsed. Do you have that set?

Comment: Also, it'd help if you added some sample code showing how you're making your call.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the tip about HTTParty#format. I had been looking for something like that. Unfortunately, adding `format :json` doesn't affect the result at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact problem the other day. There is a bug in the json parser that HTTParty uses (Crack gem) - basically it uses a case-sensitive regexp for the Unicode sequences, so because Posterous puts out A-F instead of a-f, Crack isn't unescaping them. I submitted a pull request to fix this.

In the meantime HTTParty nicely lets you specify alternate parsers so you can do `::JSON.parse` bypassing Crack entirely like this:

```
class JsonParser < HTTParty::Parser
  def json
    ::JSON.parse(body)
  end
end

class Posterous
   include HTTParty
   parser ::JsonParser

   #....
end
```

Comment: +1 I just noticed your answer, a year and a half later. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to this problem. I ran across [this gist](https://gist.github.com/664833). elskwid had the identical problem and ran the string through a JSON parser:

```
s = ::JSON.parse("\\u003Cp\\u003E")
```

Now, `s = "<p>"`.

Comment: I've edited the original question to clarify how I am making the request since it seems to be the reason for the double slashes. I'd love a better answer as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pack`:

```
"a\\u00e4\\u3042".gsub(/\\u(....)/){[$1.hex].pack("U")} # "aäあ"
```

Or to do the reverse:

```
"aäあ".gsub(/[^ -~\n]/){"\\u%04x"%$&.ord} # "a\\u00e4\\u3042"
```

Comment: Wow, this is Samurai ruby

Answer (score 0):

The doubled-backslashes almost look like a regular string being viewed in a debugger.

The string `"\u003Cp\u003E"` really is `"<p>"`, only the `\u003C` is unicode for `<` and `\003E` is `>`.

```
>> "\u003Cp\u003E"  #=> "<p>"
```

If you are truly getting the string with doubled backslashes then you could try stripping one of the pair.

As a test, see how long the string is:

```
>> "\\u003Cp\\u003E".size #=> 13
>> "\u003Cp\u003E".size #=> 3
>> "<p>".size #=> 3
```

All the above was done using Ruby 1.9.2, which is Unicode aware. v1.8.7 wasn't. Here's what I get using 1.8.7's IRB for comparison:

```
>> "\u003Cp\u003E" #=> "u003Cpu003E"
```

Comment: I get the same behavior as above using the two different versions of Ruby. The question becomes, where are the double slashes coming from? I will continue to investigate.