# Unescaping Characters in a JSON response string

Tags: json, python-2.7, unicode, escaping, posterous

I made a JSON request that gives me a string that uses [Unicode character codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) that looks like:

```
s = "\u003Cp\u003E"
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
s = "<p>"
```

What's the best way to do this in Python?

Note, this is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171201/unescaping-characters-in-a-string-with-ruby), only in Python except Ruby. I am also using the [Posterous API](http://apidocs.posterous.com/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the data came from JSON, the `json` module should already have decoded these escapes for you:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"\u003Cp\u003E"')
u'<p>'
```

Comment: I wish I could mark both these answers as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Spike: if it is JSON input, this is the real right answer. Python string literals are not completely compatible with JSON string literals and `unicode-escape` can return the wrong results for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (which JS/JSON store as surrogates but Python might not).

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> "\\u003Cp\\u003E".decode('unicode-escape')
u'<p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The original question "*Unescaping Characters in a String with Python*" did not clarify if the string was to be ***written*** or to be ***read*** (later on, the "*JSON response*" words were added, to clarify the intention was to *read*).

So I answered the opposite question: how to ***write*** JSON serialized data dumping them to a unescaped string (rather than loading data from the string).

My use case was producing a JSON file from my own data dictionary, but the file contained scaped non-ASCII characters. So I did it like this:

```
with open(filename,'w') as jsonfile:
    jsonstr = json.dumps(myDictionary, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(jsonstr)          # to screen
    jsonfile.write(jsonstr) # to file
```

If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If `ensure_ascii` is false, these characters will be output as-is.

Taken from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: heads-up: I edited the (wow almost a decade-old) Question with some hindsight and your Answer to remove some of the extra intro - feel free to revert if you don't think this was appropriate!

Comment: thanks @ti7   I prefer to clarify this answer was written before your change of the original title