# Unicode HTML Conversion to ASCII in Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unescaping Characters in a String with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555063/unescaping-characters-in-a-string-with-python)

I have a string of unicode HTML in Python which begins with: `\u003ctable>\u003ctr`
I need to convert this to ascii so I can then parse it with BeautifulSoup. However, Python's encode and decode functions seem to have no effect; I get the original string no matter what I try. I'm new to Python and unicode in general, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: BeautifulSoup can handle Unicode. In fact, it goes to great lengths to make everything unicode, with a class called "UnicodeDammit".

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I see what you mean. You've somehow got a byte string including those characters? Try `s.decode("unicode-escape")`. Or if it's in your code, write it as `u"\u003ctable>\u003ctr"`.

Comment: Yeah, you guys and Sentinel below are all correct. Thanks.

Comment: The other likely source of a `\u003c` escape is JSON. If you are receiving JSON-encoded input you should be decoding the entire thing with `json.loads` and picking out the property in question. Don't rely on `unicode-escape` if the input is actually JSON: Python and JavaScript string literals are similar but **not** the same; you'll get the wrong results for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
s.decode("unicode-escape")
```

to decode the html data first (no idea how you get this character crap from).

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you're talking about. I suspect that I'm not the only one.

```
>>> s = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(u'<html><body>\u003ctable>\u003ctr</body></html>')
>>> s
<html><body><table><tr></tr></table></body></html>
```