# Unicode characters break JSON encode/decode

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to save something as JSON, but it breaks after a Unicode character:

```
Obj: {
    comment => "test test test £466"
}
```

=> `to_json` results in

```
{
    "comment":"test test test "
}
```

`Obj.inspect` puts:

```
`comment => "test test test \243466"`
```

Any hints here?

Comment: Nevermind, I converted the incoming string with

Iconv.conv('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-1', "incoming text")

Comment: Then add an answer what is the solution and accept it. That way, your question won't hang around as unanswered. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Daniel has a solution using Iconv, namely:

```
Iconv.conv('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-1', "incoming text")
```

Is there another way to to this though? In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171201/unescaping-characters-in-a-string-with-ruby) I read that someone was having trouble with iconv on heroku